# what is difference between mutable and immutable property of collection in kotlin

Tags: collections, kotlin, corda

I am upgrading corda from version 1 to version 3.1 in IntelliJ 2017 version. I am facing the issue with not nullable property of collection

```
private var valueContractTransactionsVO = Collection<ValueContractTransactionVO>
```

I am trying to create an object for a VO class of an empty collection type like I mentioned above, but it is throwing an error "Interface collection does not have constructors" and whenever I try to call that object, it is throwing error "Unresolved Reference".

Please help me to create an object for an empty collection without it being null.

Comment: Please add some code snippets to illustrate your problem. If you had working code, please post the part you have troubles with.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an empty read-only collection, you can call the [`emptyList`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html) function:

```
var valueContractTransactionsVO: Collection<ValueContractTransactionVO> = emptyList()
```

And if the type of `valueContractTransactionsVO` being a `Collection` is not significant for your case, you can specify the type argument of the `emptyList` function and let the compiler to infer its type to `List<ValueContractTransactionVO>`:

```
var valueContractTransactionsVO = emptyList<ValueContractTransactionVO>()
```